# Verify that all key/value pairs in a Map are present in another Map

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a List of objects containing a Map.
The object looks like this :

```
public class SwiftObject {
    private Map<String, String> metadata;
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to filter my objects based on the keys and values stored in their Map.
My filter criteria are contained in another Map.
I'd like to filter and keep all the objects which Map has all key/value contained in the filter Map.

This is the code I wrote :

```
List<? extends SwiftObject> swiftObjects = documentStore.listAllObjects(container);
Map<String, String> searchMetadata = gssDocument.getMetadataMap();
List<SwiftObject> filteredSwiftObjects = swiftObjects.stream()
            .filter(swiftObject ->
                    searchMetadata.entrySet().stream()
                    .allMatch(entry -> entry.getValue().equals(swiftObject.getMetadata().get(entry.getKey())))
                    )
            .collect(Collectors.ToList());
```

Is it the right way to do this or can it be refactored/optimized?
The searchMetadata map does not contain null values

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use [`Map.equals(Map other)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) to check if both maps contain the same mappings. If you just need to check if a map is a subset of another map, use `map.entrySet().containsAll(other.entrySet())`.

Comment: Thank you @h22, I'll edit my question with your answer

Comment: @bobuns Please don't, that would make the initial problem disappear and the answer would no longer be valid.

Comment: @bobuns: DON’T copy answers into your question. The accepted answer will always appear right beneath your question. By accepting an answer, you are already telling that it’s a solution that works for you.

Comment: OT: I found this question looking for testing map inclusion in unit tests using AssertJ library. This library provides `containsAllEntriesOf` method. Hence to assert the map contains at least the required expected entries, use `assertThat(actual).containsAllEntriesOf(expected)` .