# Java: Map Contains Equals to or Less Than of Another Map

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, hashmap, contains

How do I check if 1 subset contains less than or equal to of another subset? SMap and TMap below.

In this example, doing equation returns false.

```
sMap.entrySet().containsAll(tMap.entrySet())
```

I believe it returns false, since it is trying equal the count of A,B,C.  {1,2,2} does Not equal {1,1,1}.  However, it should be true since {1,1,1} <= {1,2,2} for each element A,B,C.

Is there an easy method to doing a contains less than or equal to?  Otherwise I will just write a manual for loop with count.

[image]

[Check whether a map contains all contents of another map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217055/check-whether-a-map-contains-all-contents-of-another-map)

[Verify that all key/value pairs in a Map are present in another Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33024356/verify-that-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-map-are-present-in-another-map)

Comment: There are two answers below. Can you clarify why they're not satisfactory and what you're looking for?

Comment: You could implement a custom Map that provides a custom Entry implementation that overrides the containsAll function that does the check...but this Is definitely not an easy way of doing it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, there is no built-in method to do what you desire, `containsAll` returns `true` when all the map entries from one map exist in another map.

But, as you said you can write such a method as below;

```
private static boolean containsAllCounts(Map<String, Integer> firstMap, Map<String, Integer> secondMap) {
    String key;
    int secondMapCount;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : secondMap.entrySet()) {
        key = entry.getKey();
        secondMapCount = entry.getValue();
        if (!firstMap.containsKey(key) || firstMap.get(key) <= secondMapCount) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

When there are two maps as below;

```
    Map<String, Integer> firstMap = new HashMap<>();
    firstMap.put("A", 2);
    firstMap.put("B", 2);
    firstMap.put("C", 1);

    Map<String, Integer> secondMap = new HashMap<>();
    secondMap.put("A", 1);
    secondMap.put("B", 1);

    System.out.println(containsAllCounts(firstMap, secondMap));
    System.out.println(containsAllCounts(secondMap, firstMap));
```

Outputs will be;

```
true
false
```

Answer (score 2):

The equal method will compare the hash and therefore only for equality. I am not aware of a build in function, but with an `allMatch` on the stream you could do a compare easily on your own...

With allMatch (thanks to @shmosel):

```java
    tMap.entrySet()
         .stream()
         .allMatch(e -> sMap.containsKey(e.getKey()) && sMap.get(e.getKey()) >= e.getValue())
```

---- edited, originally I had the noneMatch example but allMatch is easier to understand...for completeness, I still include the noneMatch example -----

```java
    tMap.entrySet().stream().noneMatch(entry -> {
        final Integer match = sMap.get(entry.getKey());
        return match == null || entry.getValue() > match;
    });
```

or if you prefer it as a one-liner

```java
    tMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .noneMatch(entry -> !sMap.containsKey(entry.getKey()) || entry.getValue() > sMap.get(entry.getKey()));
```

The matcher will check for any unmatched key or value from tMap, that is greater than the value in sMap.

Comment: This will allow keys in `tMap` that don't exist in `sMap`. I think OP needs `allMatch(e -> sMap.containsKey(e.getKey()) && sMap.get(e.getKey()) >= e.getValue())`.

Comment: @shmosel No, that is not right. The filter !sMap.containsKey(entry.getKey()) will return true if tMap has entries, that are not in sMap and then the noneMatch is going to return false...I just wrote a test to verify it...

Comment: My bad, you're right. But I think my way is a little more readable as it avoids the double negative.

Comment: I just added your example, you are right, the positive way is easier to understand

Comment: If you want to avoid double-lookup, you can use `.allMatch(e -> sMap.getOrDefault( e.getKey(), Integer.MIN_VALUE) > e.getValue() - 1L))`